Following ros4hri tutorial for ros noetic and stuck on installing ros4hri hri_face_detect
Im quite new to ros so apologies if this is a very basic question. I am following the ros4hri tutorials running ros noetic and im stuck on installing the hri_face_detect repository. Ive tried cloning it, changing it to main branch (as i assume that is the noetic version and I dont want humble which is default) and building but I just seem to always get stuck as catkin make and rosdep install fails. Any guidance is very much appreciated, thankyou.

Hi! Could you provide some more info on the error message you get from the build attempt?
